# Python Find indices of data in array/list, but with constraints

Tags: python, arrays, list, find, indices

I have three arrays (or lists, or whatever):

`x` - The abscissa. A set of data which is not evenly spaced.

`y` - The ordinate. A set of data representing `y=f(x)`.

`peaks` - A set of data whose elements contain and ordered pair `(x,y)`, which represent the peak values found in `y`.

Here is a portion of the `x` and `y` data:

```
2.00   1.5060000000e-07
...
...
5.60   3.4100000000e-08
5.80   1.7450000000e-07
6.00   7.1700000000e-08
6.20   5.2900000000e-08
6.40   2.5570000000e-07
6.50   4.8420000000e-07
6.60   6.1900000000e-08
6.80   2.2700000000e-07
7.00   2.3500000000e-08
7.20   3.6500000000e-08
7.40   1.0158000000e-06
7.50   3.5100000000e-08
7.60   2.0080000000e-07
7.80   1.6585000000e-06 
8.00   2.1190000000e-07
8.20   5.3370000000e-07
8.40   5.7840000000e-07
8.50   4.5230000000e-07
...
...
50.00   1.8200000000e-07
```

Here is `print(peaks)`:

```
[(3.7999999999999998, 4.0728000000000002e-06), (5.4000000000000004, 5.4893000000000001e-06), (10.800000000000001, 1.2068e-05), (12.699999999999999, 4.1904799999999999e-05), (14.300000000000001, 8.3118000000000006e-06), (27.699999999999999, 6.5239000000000003e-06)]
```

I use the data to make a plot, similar to this:

[image]

The blue dots in the plot are the peaks. And the red dots are the valleys. But the red dots are not necessarily accurate. You can see there is a red dot to the right of the last peak. That was not intended.

Using the data above, I am attempting to find the valleys as follows:

Go through the `peaks` array (or list, or whatever it is) and for each adjacent pair of peaks, find their indices in the `x` and `y` arrays (or lists, or whatever they are), then search the `y` array bound by those indices for the minimum value. Also find the corresponding `x` value at that index. Then append the `(x,y)` pair to an array `v1` (or list, or whatever), which will be like `peaks`. Then plot `v1` as red dots.

Here is the code:

```
for i in xrange(1,len(peaks)):
# Find the indices of the two peaks in the actual arrays
# (e.g. x[j1] and y[j1]) where the peaks occur
  j1=np.where(x==peaks[i-1][0])
  j1=int(j1[0])
  j2=np.where(x==peaks[i][0])
  j2=int(j2[0])
# In the array y[j1:j2], find the index of the minimum value
  j=np.where(y==min(y[j1:j2]))
# What if there are more than one minumum?
  if(len(j[0])>1):
# Use the first one.
# I incorrectly assumed this would be > j1,
# but it could be anywhere in y
    jt=int(j[0][0])
    v1.append((x[jt],y[jt]))
# And the last one.
# I incorrectly assumed this would be < j2,
# but it could be anywhere in y. But we do know at least one of the
# indices found will be between j1 and j2.
    jt=int(j[0][-1])
    v1.append((x[jt],y[jt]))
  else:
# When only 1 index is found, no problem: it has to be j1 < j < j2
    j=int(j[0])
    v1.append((x[j],y[j]))
```

Here is the problem:

When I search for the minimum value(s) of `y` in a certain range like this:

```
j=np.where(y==min(y[j1:j2]))
```

It returns the indices of those minimum throughout the entire data set of `y`.  But I want `j` to contain only the indices of the minimum between `j1` and `j2`, where I searched.

How can I constrain the search?

I could check to see if j1 < j < j2, but I would prefer to constrain the search to return only values of j in that range, if possible.

Once I figure that out, then I will add logic to limit the indices if the peaks are more than a width `w` apart.

So if the peaks are more than `w` apart, then `j1` will be no less than `j2-w/2`, where `j2` is the index of the peak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could slice the array before and do the `==` comparison with the slice:

```
sliced_y = y[j1:j2]
j = np.where(sliced_y == min(sliced_y))[0] + j1
```

You need to `+` the lower bound, otherwise you only have the "index" with respect to the sliced part.

Comment: `    j=np.where(ys==min(ys))+j1
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple`

Comment: @Mannix It seems you forgot the `[0]` after `np.where(...)`?